# How to calculate a date from user input date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

How to calculate a date from date inputs using javascript?
Here is my code:

```
<p>
  Start date: <input id="start" name="start" placeholder="Start Date(mm/dd/yyyy)" type="date" />
</p>
<p>
  End date: <input id="end" name="end" placeholder="End Date(mm/dd/yyyy)" type="date" />
</p>
```

I want to display a date by adding 17 months to the end date

Comment: look at momentjs. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the value of the end date with JQuery like this:

```
var endDate = $("#end").val();
```

Then turn it into a date object:

```
endDate = new Date(endDate);
```

You can then add 515 (365 for 12 months, and 300 for the extra 5 months approx.) days to the date like this:

```
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()+515);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following and add 17 months

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setMonth( myDate.getMonth() + 17 );
alert(myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) library you can do it with:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/4ctL4ju4/1/)

```
var yourDate = new Date(),
    newDate = moment(yourDate).add(17, 'months');

console.log(newDate.format());
```